# php inline function like .net

Tags: php, function, inline, inline-functions

i want to write an inline function in php like below

forexample :

```
$c = getCountry();
$b = getZones();
$a = [
      'x' => function() use ($c, $b)
             {
                 if ( isset($c[0]) )
                     return getZonesByCountryId($c[0]['id']);
                 else
                     return $b;
             }
     ];
```

i get this error : "Object of class Closure could not be converted to string"
i write inline function in .net like i did it above. please help me !!!

Comment: *This* code does not throw *that* error. Something that's trying to `echo` the value of `$a['x']` later on throws that error. Are you expecting the function to be executed immediately and its *result* assigned to `x`...?

Comment: Which version of php do you use?

Answer (score 4):

The value of `'x'` is going to be *a function*; the anonymous function itself will be assigned to `'x'`, not its return value. To assign its return value, you need to actually execute the function:

```
$a = ['x' => call_user_func(function() use ($c, $b) {
          if (isset($c[0])) {
              return getZonesByCountryId($c[0]['id']);
          } else {
              return $b;
          }
      })];
```

However, in this particular case it makes absolutely no sense to use such a complicated solution, when this will do just fine:

```
$a = ['x' => isset($c[0]) ? getZonesByCountryId($c[0]['id']) : $b];
```